# How to import the Confluence API with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I need to work with the Confluence API.

I work with Maven POM but I don't find how to insert the dependencies for the Confluence API.

Can you help me?

What I've already tried:
I need to work with the [SpaceManager](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/latest/com/atlassian/confluence/spaces/SpaceManager.html) primaly.
I found [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Managing+Dependencies) tutorial about managing the pom. So after the tutorial, my pom looks like the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>***.createspace</groupId>
    <artifactId>CreateSpace</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>CreateSpace</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-confluence-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <productVersion>${product.version}</productVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence</groupId>
            <artifactId>confluence</artifactId>
            <version>${confluence.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>    <!-- important! -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The `***` in the groupId is just to hide my package name of my company.

But also with this pom, I get the error `The import com.atlassian cannot be resolved` with this import:

```
import com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.SpaceManager;
```

So can you help me? Or please tell me what I should add to avoid downvotes, then I hope you see I really searched in the net and need help!

Comment: This one http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.hudson/confluence-api ? Find the api you need and add the dependency to the pom.

Comment: @Zilvinas: YES! But they only write something about a SDK to download, but I'm not able to install something. And in no single tutorial I found is something about the set up of the confluence atlassian with maven

Comment: So you have the confluence dependency marked as provided.  Do you have the jar in the classpath?  Is the SpaceManager class part of that dependency, or is it defined in the maven plugin?

Comment: You could try flipping that confluence dependency to <scope>compile</scope>

Comment: Also, to be clear, even if you use Maven, you're still downloading the required SDK libs.  They're just living in your local maven repository.  In any case, as I said above, if you want to use the <scope>provided</scope> as you have it, you'll have to download the jar and get it on the classpath.

Comment: @jgitter: No I haven't downloaded the jar. I also shouldn't do that as far as I know when I work with maven. Yes, I know it will download itself, so I shouldn't download it...? What exactly will this <scope> do?

Comment: Here is a link to the dependency scope mechanism documentation for maven that you should read.  http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope  In a nutshell, a scope of provided means you are declaring that a library is required, but will be provided by some other means.  It is usually used for things like jdbc drivers or container java-ee libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are instructions how to work with atlassian maven repo [Atlassian Maven Repositories](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Atlassian+Maven+Repositories) and the repo URL is provided: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<repository>
  <id>atlassian-public</id>
  <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
  </snapshots>
   <releases>
     <enabled>true</enabled>
     <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
  </releases>
</repository>
```

If you're trying to add a plugin for confluence WIKI you'll probably need a dependency to:

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<groupId>com.atlassian.confluence</groupId>
<artifactId>confluence</artifactId>
```

( only once you add the atlassian maven repo to your pom.xml ) so full `pom.xml` will look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.vilutis.lt</groupId>
    <artifactId>confluence-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>confluence-plugin</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>atlassian-public</id>
            <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <!-- I had to add this section because activation-1.0.2.jar does not exist in public maven repo -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence</groupId>
            <artifactId>confluence</artifactId>
            <version>5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This config works fine with version 5.2 and the `SpaceManager` class is accessible in your java code.

Comment: I added exactly that in my pom. But nothing happend. It always sais it can't resolve `com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.SpaceManager`...

Comment: please take a look to my edit, mybe it help you to understand my problem better

Comment: So you've set your dependency to "provided" and I don't see the value of "confluence.version" so I cannot tell you anything, but the [confluence-5.2.jar](https://maven.atlassian.com/content/groups/public/com/atlassian/confluence/confluence/5.2/confluence-5.2.jar) does contain this class. So if you did the configuration the way I explained you should now see the jar when using version 5.2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with Confluence API implementation you're using.  You could try this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.hudson</groupId>
  <artifactId>confluence-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're using an implementation that doesn't support maven builds, then you'll have to add the transitive dependencies yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly, when I insert this in my pom, nothing happens... I don't know if it's wrong or I need something additional. I'm really confused about the doc by atlassian....

Comment: please take a look to my edit, mybe it help you to understand my problem better

Answer (score 0):

In this case confluent.version is 3.0.0

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-config</artifactId>
        <version>${confluent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-utils</artifactId>
        <version>${confluent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
        <version>${confluent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
        <version>${confluent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```